# Caliburn.micro: Deep property change INPC catching in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a View where I bind some deep properties of a Model (using the naming convention of Caliburn.Micro):

**View:**

```
   <UserControl x:Class="TOP.SomeView" 
   (...)
    <TextBox x:Name="NewFooModel_Foo" .../>
```

Then I need to catch the firing of the INPC of that property in the ViewModel:

**Model:**

```
public class FooModel{


        private string _foo;
(...)

        public int Foo {
            get { return _foo; }
            set {
                if (_foo != value) {
                    _foo = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Foo);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

From that point, the property of the model is binded correctly. So, I need that change to be notified to the CanCreateFoo and I don't know how:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class SomeViewModel{

(...)

      public FooModel NewFooModel {
            get { return _newFooModel; }
            set {
                if (_newFooModel != value) {
                    _newFooModel = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Foo);
    //HERE I NEED TO NOTIFY TO CANCREATEFOOMODEL THAT A PROPERTY OF THE MODEL IS CHANGED
                }
            }
        }

   public bool CanCreateFooModel{
      get{
         return NewFooModel.Foo != null;
      }
   }
}
```

Please,  can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanCreateFooModel)` in your `NewFooModel` setter...

Comment: Ok, but I use this Model in different ViewModels, so I have to create a NOFC in every one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use EventAggregator to publish a message when the Property changes (and also NotifyOfPropertyChange for your current VM).
Each Model which is interested can subscribe to this message and handle it.

Comment: Thank, I'm not already in that project but it could help someone else :-)